# Bluetooth not working Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04

I'm using a generic dongle and it was working fine with Bionic Beaver and Cosmic Cuttlefish. After updating to 19.04, I can't get it to work and this is a similar problem that I noticed in arch linux using gnome desktop.

```
abhishek@redgear:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]#
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Not so sure but mine works perfectly well. Ubuntu Desktop 19.04. Ongoing and Incoming files work.